# How to add reference from storyboard to Kotlin file

Tags: xcode, kotlin, interface-builder, appcode, kotlin-native

I've created a sample `Kotlin/Native` iOS app using `AppCode`. It runs perfectly fine. The sample app contains one `UILabel`, one `UITextField` and a `Button`. When the user clicks the button, the textfield data will be shown in the label.

Now, I've added a new button using `XCode`'s `InterfaceBuilder`, but I don't know how to connect the button to the `ViewController.kt` file. Usually, when using `Swift`, a simple drag and drop from the `InterfaceBuilder` to the `Swift` file would automatically make the connection. But in my case it's not a `Swift` file, but `Kotlin`.

**How do i make the connection to the `Kotlin` view controller file from the `InterfaceBuilder`** ? I tried the drag and drop, but it doesn't work.

I tried manually editing the storyboard file using a text editor and added the connection. It did work. but I don't feel like it as a perfect solution. **Is there any alternative?**

Below given the screenshot of the App.

Here's the [github link](https://github.com/theapache64/Konan/tree/91b6beab1a5c6692cad8509aa47b0f772caba333) for the source code.

[image: Sample app]